# stored procedures as queries: CallableStatement vs. PreparedStatement

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc, prepared-statement, callable-statement

[PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-callproc.html) recommends using a [`CallableStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) to call stored procedures.

In the case of a stored procedure that returns a rowset, what are the differences between using `CallableStatement`:

```
String callString = "{ call rankFoos(?, ?) }";
CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall(callString);
callableStatement.setString(1, fooCategory);
callableStatement.setInt(2, minimumRank);
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
```

And using a regular [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
String queryString = "SELECT FooUID, Rank FROM rankFoos(?, ?);";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
preparedStatement.setString(1, fooCategory);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, minimumRank);
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
```

As I understand, `CallableStatement` offers a language-agnostic way of calling stored procedures. This doesn't matter to me though, since I know I'm using PostgreSQL. As far as I can see, the obvious advantage of using the `PreparedStatement` is a more versatile query, treating the stored procedure as a table, on which I can use `WHERE`, `JOIN`, `ORDER BY`, etc.

Are there aspects or differences between the methods that I'm missing? In the case of a stored procedure used as a query, which is recommended?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the second approach does not work at all with some RDBMS's, but since you are only going to use PostgreSQL, that shouldn't matter too much. For your simple case, there really isn't much of a downside. There are two issues I can see popping up:

1. Depending on how the stored procedures are written, they may require you to register out parameters in order to execute the procedure. That's not going to be possible at all with prepared statements. If you control both the creation of the stored procedure and the calling code, you probably don't have to worry about this.
2. It limits the effectiveness of calling stored procedures in the first place. One of the main advantages of a stored procedure is to encapsulate the querying logic at the database level. This allows you to tune the query or in some cases add functionality without having to make changes to your code. If you're planning on adding where clauses joins to the results of the stored procedure call, why not just put the original query in your java layer?

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is independence and encapsulated way of programming.

Imagine that you are a Java Programmer and you don't know how to use Database, in this way you can not use the second method and u will meet problems in the second way.

First method allows you to do your java code, and ask somebody to write the quires for you as Stored-Procedure, so u can use them easily.

I do agree with @dlawrence